# Fultter app stopped working after flutter clean

Tags: flutter, build, flutter-android

I wanted to integraate flutter_sms plugin in my app, and it wasn't working so, i tried flutter clean command, followed by flutter pub get and flutter cache repair. But, my application isn't even building now. It throws this error when i try to run it

```
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:19: error: package io.flutter.plugins.camera does not exist
  flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.camera.CameraPlugin());
                                                                  ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:24: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin());
                                                                              ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:29: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin());
                                                                         ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:34: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin());
                                                                         ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:39: error: package io.flutter.plugins.regula.faceapi.flutter_face_api does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.regula.faceapi.flutter_face_api.FlutterFaceApiPlugin());
                                                                                          ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:44: error: package io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin());
                                                                                          ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:49: error: package com.baseflow.geolocator does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.baseflow.geolocator.GeolocatorPlugin());
                                                                ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:54: error: package com.b.biradar.google_ml_kit does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.b.biradar.google_ml_kit.GoogleMlKitPlugin());
                                                                    ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:59: error: package io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin());
                                                                       ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:64: error: package io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin());
                                                                        ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:69: error: package com.tekartik.sqflite does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());
                                                             ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:74: error: package com.tfliteflutter.tflite_flutter_plugin does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tfliteflutter.tflite_flutter_plugin.TfliteFlutterPlugin());
                                                                                ^
/Users/mansi/Desktop/face_detection_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:79: error: package io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin());
                                                                       ^
13 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:face_detection_app/screens/locator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'screens/welcome_screen.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // final cameras = await availableCameras();
  // final firstCamera = cameras.first;
  setupServices();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: WelcomeScreen()
    );
  }
}
```

and my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: face_detection_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.18
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.15
  geolocator: ^8.2.1
  camera: ^0.9.5
  path_provider: ^2.0.10
  path: ^1.8.1
  google_ml_kit: ^0.5.0
  image: ^3.1.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  url_launcher: ^6.1.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  tflite_flutter: ^0.9.0
  sqflite: ^2.0.2+1
  flutter_face_api: ^3.2.2
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.16
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  network_to_file_image: ^4.0.1
  flutter_downloader: ^1.7.4
  mailer: ^5.1.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.3.2



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        package: io.flutter.plugins.regula.faceapi.flutter_face_api
        pluginClass: FlutterFaceApiPlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: FlutterFaceApiPlugin
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/mobilefacenet.tflite
    - assets/images/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

And, my app/build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.face_detection_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:17.0.1'
}
```

and my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The project was working well before flutter clean, and now it is giving these errors. Can someone please help me out with this. I am stuck here for days :(

Answer (score 0):

Try removing caches before. After that open `pubspec.yaml` then run `--no-color pub get` and/or `--no-color pub upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work :(. It is still giving the same error

Comment: @Mansi any updates? how did you fix this?